Error uploading large file on fails using php and nginx ingress
I am currently running into an issue on PHP trying to upload a video.
It returns an error saying. I am running laravel php on GKE and using nginx-ingress.
I have updated the necessary values in php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
memory_limit = 1024M

I also added the annotations to ingress:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size

<br />
<b>Warning</b>: POST Content-Length of 61828655 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in <b>Unknown</b> on line
<b>0</b><br />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive" />
    <title>An Error Occurred: Content Too Large</title>
    <link rel="icon"
        href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>❌</text></svg>" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #222;
            font: 16px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .container {
            margin: 30px;
            max-width: 600px;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #dc3545;
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Oops! An Error Occurred</h1>
        <h2>The server returned a "413 Content Too Large".</h2>

        <p>
            Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred.
            We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

Any idea or help on what i can do to fix this issue? Thanks for the help

server {
        ....
        client_max_body_size 1024M;
        ....
    }

remember to restart nginx
sudo nginx -s reload

or 

sudo nginx -s restart

Remember to restart php fpm also

where should i add this? once i add this in the pod and reload, it resets back to default

and i added this to the nginx.conf file

check on ls  /etc/nginx/site-enabled/ I want to know your block if is default add on default

but changes must be done on /etc/nginx/site-available
